# tui-calendar.js:3512 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [tui.Calendar](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.calendar/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) in reactjs, i read the documentation to get started with it, but when i try to include the calendar it gave me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` using the debugger in `tui-calendar.js:3512` `ymd = matches[0].split(separator);` here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'tui-calendar';

export default class Ttt extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
            defaultView: 'month',
            taskView: true,
            template: {
              monthGridHeader: function(model) {
                var date = new Date(model.date);
                var template = '<span class="tui-full-calendar-weekday-grid-date">' + date.getDate() + '</span>';
                return template;
              }
            }
          });
      }
    render() {
            return <div id="calendar" style={{height: 800 + 'px'}}></div>
        }
}
```

Anyone can help me face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your DIV doesn't exist yet when you create the calendar class - render function just tells react what your component should look like. Additionally, you will create a new calendar instance every time your div needs to update, which is probably not what you want.

Instead, it should be created in a different lifecycle method:

```
render() {
  ...
  return <div id="calendar" style={{height: 800}}></div>;
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.calendar = new Calendar(...)
}
```

This is still not ideal because it will break if your component is removed (check if the library provides a method to destroy a calendar instance and place it in `componentWillUnmount`). It also doesn't support multiple calendar components, which can be fixed by assigning a different ID to every instance.